# How to serialized object of ViewGroup in Android?

Tags: android

I have use this code but its not working and i do not serialized `ViewGroup` `Object` I have use this code but its not working and i do not serialized `ViewGroup` object .

```
 public void saveObject(ViewGroup v){
   try
   {

   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saved_image_file)); //Select where you wish to save <span id="IL_AD3" class="IL_AD">the file</span>...
                   oos.writeObject(v); // write the class as an 'object'
                   oos.flush(); // flush the <span id="IL_AD8" class="IL_AD">stream</span> to insure all of the information was written to 'save_object.bin'
                   oos.close();// close the stream
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                   Log.v("Serialization Save Error : ",ex.getMessage());
                   ex.printStackTrace();
                }
           }

           public ViewGroup loadSerializedObject(File f)
           {
               try
               {


                   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                   Log.e("object sasasasasa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
                   Log.e("object sasasasasa", ois.readObject()+"");
                   ViewGroup o =(ViewGroup)ois.readObject();
                   return o;

               }
               catch(Exception ex)
               {
               Log.v("Serialization Read Error : ",ex.getMessage());
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }
               return null;
           }
```

but i got some error when store the viewGroup object in phone , please help me ...

```
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578): java.io.NotSerializableException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at com.ebabu.wireframe.saveView.saveObject(saveView.java:28)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at com.ebabu.wireframe.NavigationDrawerActivity.saveImage(NavigationDrawerActivity.java:951)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at com.ebabu.wireframe.NavigationDrawerActivity$1.run(NavigationDrawerActivity.java:317)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 13:46:57.430: W/System.err(23578):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 13:46:57.440: W/System.err(23578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-17 13:46:57.440: W/System.err(23578):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-17 13:46:57.440: W/System.err(23578):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i have put the error now you help me please .

Comment: What unclear is in this `NotSerializableException`?

Comment: `ViewGroup` is not serializable, you don't serialize anything from view hierarchy. Check the [source from 2.3](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java), you might understand why. I suggest making a custom holder class.

Answer (score 0):

[`ViewGroup`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java) extends [`View`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java) which does *not* implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). So, this is impossible.